# SQL Where IN but match all

Tags: sql

I've been searching around on the web and SO and can't find a straight forward answer to this issue - it seems like something really really obvious but I'm having no luck.

I have a SQL query which has the line:

```
WHERE Genre IN ('Rock', 'Popular', 'Classical')
```

However what this does is give a long list of results, namely does a OR however what i want instead are results that match all 3.

Thanks.

Comment: No record can match all 3 on one field.  How could it?  You need to show your data layout and some sample data and expected results if you want us to make sense of this.

Comment: As Don Roby said - How could one field/column match more than one(1) of the given categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, but I like Gordon's approach as well:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable
WHERE genre IN ('Rock', 'Popular', 'Classical')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Genre) = 3
```

This counts the distinct genres associated with an id and only returns the ones that match all 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  I advocate using aggregation with a `having` clause.

Here is an approximation of such a query:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when genre = 'Rock' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and      -- has Rock
       sum(case when genre = 'Popular' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and   -- has Popular
       sum(case when genre = 'Classical' then 1 else 0 end) > 0     -- has Classical
```

The `having` clause may look a little complicated.  But each clause is just counting the number of rows that match one of the values.  If there are any, then that genre passes that test.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) c
FROM table
WHERE Genre IN ('Rock', 'Popular', 'Classical')
GROUP BY id
HAVING c = 3
```

This assumes the combinations `id, Genre` are unique, which they should be in a properly normalized schema.